# jQuery problem with if()

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to filtering two links (containing 'next' and 'previous'), then if it finds one of them I append a link to load a photo. My problem is that I want append only one link at time, the Load Next link if it find the Next text and the Prev. link if it find the Previous text. If I write this it won't work

```
$(document).ready(function(){

if  ($(".forumrow table").find('a').filter(':contains(Next)')) {
$('.blockhead a').filter('a:last[href^="http://site.com/showgallery.php?cat="]').html('<a class="loadnextone" href="#">Load next</a>');
$('a.loadnextone').live("click",function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
var next1 = $(".forumrow table").find('a').filter(':contains(Next)').attr('href');
var next1cat1split =  $('.blockhead a').filter('a:last[href^="http://site.com/showgallery.php?cat="]').attr('href').split(/=/)[1];
$(".nextoz").load(next1+" ol.floatcontainer");
});
}

if ($(".forumrow table").find('a').filter(':contains(Prev)')) {
$('.blockhead a').filter('a:last[href^="http://site.com/showgallery.php?cat="]').html('<a class="loadprevone" href="#">Load prev</a>');
$('a.loadprevone').live("click",function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
var prev1 = $(".forumrow table").find('a').filter(':contains(prev)').attr('href');
var prev1cat1split =  $('.blockhead a').filter('a:last[href^="http://site.com/showgallery.php?cat="]').attr('href').split(/=/)[1];
$(".prevozz").load(prev1+" ol.floatcontainer");
});
}

});
```

How can I do?

Comment: please shorten this code to something much, much briefer and to the point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check for `length` property like this. `jQuery` always returns a `jQuery` object even if the selector do not return anything.

```
if  ($(".forumrow table").find('a').filter(':contains(Next)').length > 0){

}
```

and

```
if ($(".forumrow table").find('a').filter(':contains(Prev)').length > 0) {

}
```

Comment: Yes it works :-) What about if I have both links (the previous and the next one) on the same page? Btw please forgive me for my English (and I have to wait 7 minutes to accept the answer)

Comment: The filter will only look for the matching selector so dont wory. No problem accept it whenever you can thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot Shankar, so can I write also this

Comment: if  ($(".forumrow table").find('a').filter(':contains(Next)').length > 0) && ($(".forumrow table").find('a').filter(':contains(Prev)').length > 0) {

}